# Excel CSV help Python

Tags: python, arrays, excel, csv, multidimensional-array

I have the following CSV file:
[image]

How do I import the numbers only into an array in python one row at a time?  No date, no string.

My code:

```
import csv

def test():
    out = open("example.csv","rb")
    data = csv.reader(out)
    data = [row for row in data]
    out.close()
    print data
```

Let me more clear. I don't want a huge 2D array. I want to import just the 2nd row and then manipulate the data then get the 3rd row. I would need a for loop for this, but I am not sure on how csv fully works.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: How many of these have you got? If it's just this, can't you just delete the first row and column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
with open('the_CSV_file.csv','r') as f:
  box = f.readlines()

result_box = []
for line in box[1:]:
  items = line.split(';') # adjust the separator character in the CSV as needed
  result_box.append(items[1:])

print result_box
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% <csv # just a silly CSV I got from http://secrets.d8u.us/csv
Secret,Timestamp
Forza la fiera!,1368230474
American healthcare SUXXXXX,1368232342
I am not sure if I wanna take the girl out again,1368240406
I bred a race of intelligent penguin assassins to murder dick cheney. ,1368245584
"I guess it is my mother's time of the month, as it were",1368380424
i've seen walls breath,1368390258

In [33]: %paste
with open('csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
       csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel') # excel may be the default, but doesn't hurt to be explicit
       csv_reader.next()
       for row in csv_reader:
              array.append(row[1:])
## -- End pasted text --

In [34]: array
Out[34]: 
[['1368230474'],
 ['1368232342'],
 ['1368240406'],
 ['1368245584'],
 ['1368380424'],
 ['1368390258']]
```

Answer (score 0):

*corrected as per @DSM's comment*

You should end up with what you want in `array`:

```
import csv

with open('theFile.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)

    array = []
    next(reader)    # skips 'string's row
    for row in reader:
        numberRow = [float(x) for x in row[1:]) # This slice skips 'date's
        array.append(numberRow)
```

I'm not sure it's necessary to define the encoding.  But if you want to treat these as numbers, you will have to use `float(x)`, or else they'll just be strings.

Comment: This won't work as written because you can't slice a `csv.reader` instance.  I think the usual idiom is `next(reader)` and then the usual `for row in reader:`.

Comment: Thanks @DSM.  My original answer had `for row in reader[1:]` and no `next(reader)`